# Why have those flags been declined?

Tags: discussion

I flagged a number of old questions with no user activity for a long time as "probably obsolete,....". Three of the flags have been declined but I don't see what makes those three questions different.

The questions were:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164352/dell-1545-cannot-connect-to-belkin-n300-router-how-to-fix-it

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164358/how-to-make-ubuntu-12-04-kernel-3-2-wake-htpc

https://askubuntu.com/questions/164506/multiple-startup-script-issue

Comment: I assume Luis didn't mark them as helpful ...

Comment: Actually I had a problem with the mouse and clicked on the wrong option 3 times. Already corrected the problem (Batteries were almost dead) and the questions guntbert marked (And also the other 2000000 you marked as abandoned ^^). Sorry for the mix up.

Comment: @LuisAlvarado no problem at all - I thought I had overlooked something obvious - and there won't be such a flood in the near future - I only went through the last two pages of "Unanswerded/no answers".

Comment: @FEichinger **how** did you reach that conclusion?

Comment: @guntbert Luis closed all of those questions - which means he was most likely the one who handled your flags and just forgot/misclicked/whatnot as to whether or not your flag was valid.

Comment: @guntbert Got nothing against your flood of flagged questions. I actually have a top 10 list of users I trust when they flag like that and you are one of them and even though I still go through each question one by one I know that the top 10 took their time to verify the quality of the question/answer/comment and any other related variable before flagging it. You are doing an excellent job if anybody asks me.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The problem was do to a malfunctioning pointing device that had a self guidance automatic cursor movement with advanced AI implemented. The mouse knew where to click without user interaction.

Or in normal language: My mouse sucks. The batteries started dying and every time I moved the mouse to click somewhere it "magically" moved somewhere else nearby. The best part is that if I clicked it would move THEN click. So I ended up clicking 3 times before <s>killing</s> changing the mouse with new batteries.